# Matrices with positive permutation products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, terminology, determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix such that 
$$
\operatorname{sign}(\sigma) \cdot a_{1,\sigma(1)} a_{2,\sigma(2)} \ldots a_{n,\sigma(n)}\ge 0
$$
for all $\sigma\in S_n$.  Is there a name for this rather small subclass of matrices?